# How do I get the Touchpad Settings working on a Dell XPS 13" Ultrabook?

Tags: touchpad, dell, xps

Today I got an brand new Dell XPS 13 and I really like it. Wifi/Bluetooth/Brightness works very well. But only the Touchpad makes me insane. Okay, Multitouch is really nice and i love it on my Macbook but... i must click to click. How can I set up that is an "touch" to click?

Its makes me insane.

click, click, click.. Can I configure it?

**Update:** I checked the proc/devices and got:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=7
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=103
```

Its really bad - and anyone have an Idea that Ubuntu thinks that is an Touchpad??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this PPA to your system:

https://launchpad.net/~kamalmostafa/+archive/dellxps

The changes will hopefully eventually make it into the Ubuntu archive's kernel, but for now that will enable things.

Comment: This is now outdated. All changes should be in 13.04. The blogpost below - http://ken-mcconnell.com/2012/07/22/trackpad-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-on-dell-xps-13/ gives a link to a usefull tool.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like ubuntu is still fixing this
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/978807

Comment: Hope that he fix it fast

Answer (score 1):

http://ken-mcconnell.com/2012/07/22/trackpad-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-on-dell-xps-13/

this is an additional tool for tweaking your touchpad

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my XPS. A good solution is :

```
> sudo -i
> touch /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_i2c_hid.conf
> gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_i2c_hid.conf
> write : blacklist i2c_hid
> restart
```

Finally, you could have the multitouch : 'System Settings' -> 'Mouse and Touchpad'

Comment: I found this here : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2200363

Answer (score 0):

Open up 'System Settings' -> 'Mouse and Touchpad' -> click the 'Touchpad' tab and check 'Enable mouse clicks with touchpad'

Alternatively, if you would like even more control over your touchpad, open up the 'Ubuntu Software Center' and search for and install 'Synaptiks'

Comment: I saw only an "Mouse" Tab. No "Touchpad"

Comment: Appears to be a bug, the touchpad is closed source and linux drivers have not been created yet, it appears Dell recognizes this and is working to fix it - http://bartongeorge.net/2012/05/07/introducing-project-sputnik-developer-laptop/

Comment: Seems that I should wait for the driver...

Answer (score 0):

This problem was often rported and dell developped some debian packages. For me it solved the problem.

==> http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/extras/m/mediagallery/20441258

Cheers,

R.